# MudBlazor - Search table onkeypress

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am trying to figure out how I can apply "search as you type" feature to the MudTextField component using the MudBlazor table component. As of now, it searches only when enter key is pressed as seen here - [MudBlazor Table Example](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/vVlbb9s2FH7PnyhBbIAMNEqDYcPQ2FpqN108NBfMwfYwDAMtMTFXmvRIKpcF_u87h6RkyRfF3S0oLIk8N57zkfzI_vbbBRMqNexPbV6dllaoOzJ5so7P00vu0nPnFukPVquD2HdRFkOJwunZI5svJLfpe-ZYeqELLu3BqVC_89wR1BtJwZUjs_q17h1PFMs_TZkh1cvBQR8s37Cp5GQMzu2Anp5JPgctS8l7riyHlgKflJzre27gc4ZPSn7krLhS8glajIYnJSOm4F_O5VkhHDTnzW9KPgjp0IDiD-RDqfJ-9PR6qrXMktCNHT16QOq_06lQxeGESxgBLzDIAbWNr2NKJtq4j2zK5YDiKxliLHo-Fw4d34B1JxYDGpqID6bh4EqtZCFh-SeIPEl6ZJDVaUrfFUXS1CfnTBWSGzJW9_oTL2ivBwnRD9h3bfi94A8DOgTlcoEx1n0hHQP6I7fcYc-NvjLiTigmf2Ky5LYZWKXj3Q4oip8zO-Q8BgwJoGRsUQZEJw_C5TPAylDqHEKCUUzxLbTTzBvuYzKGzIy0cpD5rPbmYcAfHbl5WugBxd909g3NrrkRuhA5qVDRP4qSbd3JguWQjqNNix8El0Wsoh8jlo-ZfDZxBqKl5FqC6kzLArEx8V2UvCu0UehwQOvXdOKYcY2-ca4VDBMfNr1ggB7BZAo4krxIK0vYOxF_glv8TS94IUooyEgyC2ifu8M3NKsH5YONqTralqv-SMvvjS4XjYHmWhLrniS4eBCFm739-s3i8YS2krEh8-0eMl-_-XKLyEvfHaH0j9rh989hDvMdaJhl9dpQTzA_1YZPW-Yw0VNcY7LkcZA9ppflfMpNj2aXJuS2ZSXme_YvOpyIOwXu8PEPHY6VcACj98KAdYEAw776M31nc64Kj9x9k8HmHFMBj_8nGdfaCowVnFav_4_jCy0ZVv0C5taLHvtHW9DXh5XshsMGB7N5LbCC4I4X1_lLQ7PTHDUfXURbMF50aSE8GnortHRqYeGa3uo6dmpVmW9otovRqe0zSeaQx4a-b2wp94828tWP2wYg9L9OZGOv6lzvWwlH4vBHCdOpaK1c-5bhs316tb_rc1XEDb-QK9hv8i7XtfbK_YWABeWYfmYYTTR8dgK88h4Z8Fjaipz-NbvbtUvgBPfdqz2mLb1aB7LANgMhicGOZjySlcgqYYPSBrkaPNJrI-bMPNHMU09vKWhnXZYiXW1ZmnBIR-FteVa7r62K2TZt3XADOwSaQgpMkAPva26NEbfMjtWtphl0kyDiiea-hptUb23kZZ5zBI7nhYG9QqFJzRc3XHgeOFZSKICRMyXMuop-H78lpy3y_V1jOfSk0Fs4e1wwZQH510zB8YRMAiW5lfzxLTk-qcjohiRBG7C6zCA-4QM45Bgvv8cTjdR3Dfif3mrDGaQiuce5AUME2IEWQY0zVLC9Wvi5Hlh2GkVXMS9XNsUtSVb66UiX4Dcjb1qWCnFP8kAfi0McU2M8bR6MLcPSOa0afPMrSkIbkGxIyuo9Da-U_MSAyCL1jS-R0lI8qoQDykgCu_VBfsSk-M9VlvzQgjGcfxBvHKPvaKc8TtC1ikEdYf0oOHkmCyPuYSUgH4V1fes5e9bIMRkQIAVJ78Q7qITxREf8PIT-WyYt39LvZzz0I8S2dPup16Hemksdco2psV0qDIo0TyUgSGlbKjIe0oI_jr6UcrskD88hR6RikG0xOMvNJtxVVCprWbbHIbEbUpjplpnxmcKdCBfYlanqtBaN-NptsaCdd0iwEEZAuZl9Ujm5YfYTYC0yYTg1Fe-wPQmz4LmeCw0v7IGJ5p1D-j13H4ye4x2GV-63YsgS-sCnbCGOFvGA6XAANMJo2R7ivRYFaUF-I5TmpEXBpMMSHOb9NqeV10hi_eO60GEZbwEqqZNaAE6ljkOZRjOm7njR5Xl1I5AE3lxhZMPpOnSqadZYh0jjD4kViCRJTHCvsusp1-uWLC7Y22Wxpy0biMdWYd_Vlq74znaFqrdWWa5yuF6SL2j7MiWsbW-BAiFIydTnkejbeq497xjOsgtS225UXijMzkDj5VCMM2DBEqdfjpDk9W1OR6w7b4xeCHgHJKBEGxjzHSddmhE6m5rY0alZAWlT1fd06jZgtalede6BpUirYoki090LRLjXgKrcWSK_0awuMCszu4qCNCOsOunYXsIGcmV-ngnHPXtImhtRr9eaYYa70qjGjllZi458CVPk3kwo27L0moQnAHUBtALW5fTKFIij8Z2CbI6Y5Z_rDZPz33v7gj7XDv0BdUnqhqr8jSYPqCXdHtc-PmNjgyksycHyVaxpmttXrft6oNky3A1Z2PUUHgpPDloSyDL9bT4cQ4zfUVmA7IGCBFos-ksX_AE7i3IK_C-Qzwq1a9CKInFP83d9QOLuuDsBfgE_y3VJATCtZ1inZLTpF4EXTYZKrcnVgr9gNq6Nht3fPaHBhNo5k5L2ft3h1S9anV4LXeJ_Y4SVplNy7LmIiEQpd8A07a5Io0rNkGI4NzrgaeeOHEEE2MXIl-SQPIf9aIWzZVxJln8B)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `Immediate="true"` on the search box component to trigger the search on each keystroke. Like so:

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString" Immediate="true" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
```